# Keyboard Input over MS Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, remote-desktop, microsoft-office, language

I'm connecting to a system like so: a first hop through Remote Desktop to a Citrix environment, and a second hop through Remote Desktop to a desktop computer.

On the second system, running Windows 7, I'm seeing quite a few keys mapped to seemingly random other keys. This isn't a problem in the Citrix environment, though. I've set every language and input related setting that I could find to US English, with no luck (including: Region and Language set to English (United States), location set to United States, Keyboards and Languages set to English (United States) with all of the Advanced Key Settings turned off).

I don't experience this issue when physically using the desktop. One thing which does fix this key-remapping is to reboot the system, but soon enough my remote connection starts to see the problem again.

< types \

> types |

/ types #

? types ^

' types <

" types @

\ types ~

~ types '

{}[] don't work

| doesn't work

` doesn't work

As you can imagine, getting any development tasks done when half of the keyboard doesn't work is a pain in the neck. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so get this: Microsoft Office has its own language settings, distinct from Windows, and these language settings influence the languages which appear in the language bar.

Somehow, the language bar was picking English (Canada) as the current language, and this somehow resulted in the strange keyboard inputs. (I live in Canada, and our English keyboards are identical to those found in the States, so I don't know *why* the keys would be so badly remapped, but I digress...)

Run any Office application, bring up Options under the File page, and remove unwanted languages there. This, hopefully, addresses the problem.